# Telerik Radgrid How to add textbox column from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am adding columns to RadGrid from code behind. In NeedDataSource event, I am binding a DataTable(with 10 columns) to the radgrid.
Everything's working well till here. But I would like to have text boxes in 2 columns(on load itself, not just in edit mode).

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" ShowHeader="true" 
        OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" OnPreRender="RadGrid1_PreRender"
        AutoGenerateColumns="true" >
        <MasterTableView>
        </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

If done declarative, the column definition shall be like this. But I want it accomplished from code behind.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Qty">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <input id="<%# this.GetUniqueId("Qty", Container.DataItem)%>" name="<%# this.GetUniqueId("Qty", Container.DataItem)%>" type="text" value="<%# Eval("Quantity")%>" size="2" maxlength="3"  />
                </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create TemplateColumn like any other column type and set template object to ItemTemplate (and you can do same for HeaderTemplate and FooterTemplate). But you have to define custom template class witch will implement `ITemplate`.

You can find an example here :

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-programmatic-creation.html#Section4

Answer (score 1):

Must you use a template column? If you can directly bind your columns to a datasource field, use the GridNumericColumn. This can be dynamically added from the code behind:

```
        GridNumericColumn numColumn = new GridNumericColumn();
        numColumn.UniqueName = "ColumnId";
        numColumn.MaxLength = 20;
        numColumn.HeaderText = "My Numeric Column";
        numColumn.DataField = "Qty";
        numColumn.DataFormatString = 

        myGrid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(numColumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Use This.

   GridTemplateColumn tempCol;
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.Count; i++)
    {
        tempCol = new GridTemplateColumn();
        this.gvwRejection.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(tempCol);
        tempCol.ItemTemplate = new DynamicTemplateCoulmn"txtCategoryQty"+ , "numericTextBox");
        tempCol.HeaderText = objRejectionCategoryMasterObject[i].CategoryName.Trim();
        tempCol.UniqueName = "CategoryQty" + i;
        tempCol.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        tempCol.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        tempCol.FooterStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        RejCategoryIDs[i] = objRejectionCategoryMasterObject[i].RejCategoryID;
    }

    tempCol = new GridTemplateColumn();
    this.gvwRejection.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(tempCol);
    tempCol.ItemTemplate = new DynamicTemplateCoulmn("txtTotal", "numericTextBoxReadOnly");
    tempCol.HeaderText = "Total";
    tempCol.UniqueName = "Total";
    tempCol.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
    tempCol.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
    tempCol.FooterStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Code only answers are often not very useful.

Comment: it would probably help to include some text about what its doing

Comment: GridTemplateColumn is used to create column. after creating that column we set the different properties of that column. and then Add that colum to that Grid as i dit it in above code

 this.gvwRejection.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(tempCol);